# How is LFR/LRU implemented?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, kernel, virtual, paging

How are page replacement policies like LRU/LFU implemented ? Does the hardware MMU track the reference count(in case of LFU)?
Is it possible for it to be implemented as part of the kernel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, the hardware provides minimal support for tracking which pages are accessed, and the OS kernel then uses that to implement some kind of pseudo-LRU paging policy.

Fox example, on x86, the MMU will set the 'A' bit in the PTE (page table entry) whenever a page is accessed.  So the kernel continuously loops though all the memory in use, checking, and clearing this bit.  Any page that has the bit set has been accessed since the last sweep, and any page where the bit is (still) clear since the last sweep has not.  These pages are candidates for replacement.  The details vary from OS to OS, but generally there's some sort of queue structure(s) where these pages are tracked, and the oldest ones replaced.

Comment: Thanks. Isn't this kind of costly/inefficient? To continuously track

Comment: Its a tradeoff -- how accurate do you want your page use measurements vs how much overhead do you accept for it?

Comment: Correct.
Also, the count is usually for a page right ? Or is it for a frame ?